# Get current Order ID for Woocommerce user cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am adding a custom payment gateway to WP Woocommerce.
I want to get the current user order_id for the cart created.

I can get the cart total :

```
global $woocommerce;
$total= $woocommerce->cart->total ;
```

or with :

```
WC()->cart->get_total() ;
```

How can I call the function :

```
process_payment($order_id)
```

when I don't have the $order_id yet and I have only the cart ?

(wrong question: there is no order_id yet)

Comment: there's no order yet when you're in the cart... the order id is only present after you order something.

Comment: How can I get the Id after the payment is done ?

Comment: @iheb you should update your question to reflect what you want. you ask first how to get the order id from cart and then after purchase is complete...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the question asked initially is:

you don't have a Order ID yet in the cart.
Only after checkout is complete the Order ID exists.

The answers are not inline with the question, which probably needs to be asked again or edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you user tried a payment and it failed, you might like to check $order_id = WC()->session->get( 'order_awaiting_payment' );

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $myuser_id = (int)$order->user_id;
    $user_info = get_userdata($myuser_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['product_id']==24) {
          // Do something clever
        }
    }
    return $order_id;
}
```

This will hook into WooCommerce to Trigger custom_process_order After an Order is Placed

Comment: How can I launch the process of creating order after receiving the payment?

Comment: @lheb Saad: I didn't get you what you mean - my answer will help you get the Id after the payment is done. Also there is no order ID until above function is called

Comment: Thnx Rahman for you explication. My question is How can I call this function: where to put it and How can I call it when I don't I have the order id. I m using a separated file (notification.php) to connect with payment provider

Comment: U can just put that code under your active themes functions.php file. Do the necessary changes needed in the code.

Comment: U can check this article for setting up a redirect after order is placed. https://www.xadapter.com/woocommerce-custom-redirect-right-after-order-is-placed/

Comment: My problem is : how can I call custom_process_order function with $order_id as parameter when I don't know it yet and  I have only the cart.

Comment: This will get called when the order is placed. Before order is placed, there will not be any order id :)

Comment: @Rahman  please take a look at the code. You can save me. Thank you :)

Comment: @lheb Saad : The function custom_process_order', will get called when an order is placed, you can code there for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I have a plugin created with the file custom payment.php
containing a form to connect with the payment provider:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Clic To Pay Payment Gateway
Description: Custom payment gateway example
Author:  
Author URI: 
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/**
 * Custom Payment Gateway.
 *
 * Provides a Custom Payment Gateway, mainly for testing purposes.
 */
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_custom_gateway_class');
function init_custom_gateway_class(){

    class WC_Gateway_Custom extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        public $domain;

        /**
         * Constructor for the gateway.
         */
        public function __construct() {

            $this->domain = 'custom_payment';

            $this->id                 = 'ClictoPay';
            $this->icon               = apply_filters('woocommerce_custom_gateway_icon', '');
            $this->has_fields         = false;
            $this->method_title       = __( 'ClictoPay', $this->domain );
            $this->method_description = __( 'Allows payments with custom gateway.', $this->domain );

            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();

            // Define user set variables
            $this->title        = $this->get_option( 'title' );
            $this->description  = $this->get_option( 'description' );
            $this->instructions = $this->get_option( 'instructions', $this->description );
            $this->order_status = $this->get_option( 'order_status', 'completed' );

            // Actions
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_custom', array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );

            // Customer Emails
            add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( $this, 'email_instructions' ), 10, 3 );
        }

        /**
         * Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields.
         */
        public function init_form_fields() {

            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'   => __( 'Enable/Disable', $this->domain ),
                    'type'    => 'checkbox',
                    'label'   => __( 'Enable Clic To Pay Payment', $this->domain ),
                    'default' => 'yes'
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Title', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', $this->domain ),
                   // 'default'     => __( 'Clic to pay Payment', $this->domain ),
                    'desc_tip'    => false,
                ),
                'order_status' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Order Status', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'select',
                    'class'       => 'wc-enhanced-select',
                    'description' => __( 'Choose whether status you wish after checkout.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => 'wc-completed',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'options'     => wc_get_order_statuses()
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Description', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __( 'Payment method description that the customer will see on your checkout.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => __('Payment Information', $this->domain),
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'instructions' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Instructions', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __( 'Instructions that will be added to the thank you page and emails.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => '',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
            );
        }

        /**
         * Output for the order received page.
         */
        public function thankyou_page() {
            if ( $this->instructions )
                echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) );
        }

        /**
         * Add content to the WC emails.
         *
         * @access public
         * @param WC_Order $order
         * @param bool $sent_to_admin
         * @param bool $plain_text
         */
        public function email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text = false ) {
            if ( $this->instructions && ! $sent_to_admin && 'custom' === $order->payment_method && $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) ) {
                echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) ) . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

        public function payment_fields(){

            if ( $description = $this->get_description() ) {
              //  echo wpautop( wptexturize( $description ) );
            }


           ?>

 <form action="https://clictopay.monetiquetunisie.com/clicktopay/" method="post" name="form">

<?php $loguserid = session_id();
 /***/
global $woocommerce,$amount ,$connectdb ;

// se connecter  la base
 $connectdb=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE)or die("error 01");
$amount =number_format (  $woocommerce->cart->total, 3 , ',' ,'');
/**/
/*  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );       ,  etat='".$order_id."'    */

$querye=mysqli_query($connectdb," Update nauto  set amount='".$amount."',  session='".$loguserid ."'  ")or die(mysqli_error .' erreur');



/***/           
$refc='cd'.date('ymdHis');

//$amount =number_format (  $woocommerce->cart->total, 3 , ',' ,'');

 echo      '<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="'.$loguserid.'">   
            <input name="Reference" type="hidden" value="'.$refc.'"> 
            <input name="Montant" type="hidden" value='.$amount.' >     '; ?>
                        <input name="Devise" type="hidden" value="TND" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="affilie" value="0870172012">
            <input type="hidden" name="lg" value="en">

            <table border="0">
            <tr><td  ><input style="margin-right:105px;  border: none;
  background: no-repeat url('https://saharagift.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/payyy.png') 0 0;width:250px;height:46px;


" name="Submit"   type="submit" value=""  id="clictop"  onmouseover='if ( (document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value.length <2) || (document.getElementById("billing_last_name_field").value.length <2) || (document.getElementById("billing_email").value.length <5) || (document.getElementById("billing_address_1").value.length <5) || (document.getElementById("billing_city").value.length <2) || (document.getElementById("billing_postcode").value.length <2) || ( ! document.getElementById("billing_email").value.includes("@")) || ( ! document.getElementById("billing_email").value.includes(".")) )
{alert("Please check billing details !");
document.getElementById("clictop").disabled = true;
}
else{
document.getElementById("clictop").disabled = false;
}'  /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><img style="float:left;margin-left:10px;" src="https://saharagift.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/pmm.png"  /></td></tr>
</table>
            </form>
             <?php
        }

        /**
         * Process the payment and return the result.
         *
         * @param int $order_id
         * @return array
         */
        public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            $status = 'wc-' === substr( $this->order_status, 0, 3 ) ? substr( $this->order_status, 3 ) : $this->order_status;

            // Set order status
            $order->update_status( $status, __( 'Checkout with custom payment. ', $this->domain ) );

            // Reduce stock levels
            $order->reduce_order_stock();

            // Remove cart
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();

            // Return thankyou redirect
            return array(
                'result'    => 'success',
                'redirect'  => $this->get_return_url( $order )
            );
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_custom_gateway_class' );
function add_custom_gateway_class( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Custom'; 
    return $methods;
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'process_custom_payment');
function process_custom_payment(){

    if($_POST['payment_method'] != 'custom')
        return;

    if( !isset($_POST['mobile']) || empty($_POST['mobile']) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please add your mobile number', $this->domain ), 'error' );


    if( !isset($_POST['transaction']) || empty($_POST['transaction']) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please add your transaction ID', $this->domain ), 'error' );

}

/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_payment_update_order_meta' );
function custom_payment_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if($_POST['payment_method'] != 'custom')
        return;

    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($_POST);
    // echo "</pre>";
    // exit();

  ///  update_post_meta( $order_id, 'mobile', $_POST['mobile'] );
  ///  update_post_meta( $order_id, 'transaction', $_POST['transaction'] );
}

/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    $method = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', true );
    if($method != 'custom')
        return;

  /*  $mobile = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'mobile', true );
    $transaction = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'transaction', true );

    echo '<p><strong>'.__( 'Mobile Number' ).':</strong> ' . $mobile . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__( 'Transaction ID').':</strong> ' . $transaction . '</p>';*/
}




?>
```

the payment provider communicate with the file notfication.php (anwser detail than answer accord in case of successful payment)  :

```
<?
$ref = $_GET['Reference'];
$act = $_GET['Action'];
$par = $_GET['Param'];
define("DB_HOST", "****");
define("DB_USER", "****");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "****");
define("DB_DATABASE", "****");
// se connecter  la base
include '/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';
include '/wp-content/plugins/CustomPayment.php';
global $connectdb, $woocommerce,$amount;
$connectdb=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE)or die("error 01");
$loguserid = session_id();
/* */
$query=mysqli_query ($connectdb,"SELECT * FROM nauto  ;");

/** recupertaion  amount*/
while($col = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){ 
  $amount=$col->amount ;
} 

$querye=mysqli_query($connectdb," Update nauto  set amount='".$amount."' , ref='".$ref."'   ")or die(mysqli_error .' erreur');


switch ($act) {
case "DETAIL":
// accéder à la base et récuperer le montant
echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act."&Reponse=".$amount;
break;
case "ERREUR":
// accéder à la base et mettre à jour l’état de la transaction
$queryerr=mysqli_query($connectdb," Update nauto  set num=".$par.", etat=".$act." ")or die(mysqli_error .' erreur');
echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act. "&Reponse=OK";
break;
case "ACCORD":
// accéder à la base, enregistrer le numéro d’autorisation (dans param)
$query=mysqli_query($connectdb," INSERT INTO nauto  (num,ref,session,etat,amount) values (".$par.",".$ref.",".$loguserid.",".$etat.",".$amount.")" )or die(mysqli_error .' here');

echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act. "&Reponse=OK";
///echo "Reference=".$ref. "Action=".$act. "Reponse=ANNULATION"."Param=".$par;

break;
case "REFUS":
// accéder à la base et mettre à jour l’état de la transaction
$queryref=mysqli_query($connectdb," Update nauto  set num=".$par.", etat=".$act." ")or die(mysqli_error .' refus');
echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act. "&Reponse=OK";
break;
case "ANNULATION":
// accéder à la base et mettre à jour l’état de la transaction
$queryann=mysqli_query($connectdb," Update nauto  set num=".$par.", etat=".$act." ")or die(mysqli_error .' annulation');
echo "Reference=".$ref. "&Action=".$act. "&Reponse=OK";
break;
}
?>
```

How can I create the order after I receive the payment (case ACCORD in notification.php ) ???

Answer (score 0):

how do you create custom payment gateway?
did you create class that extends `WC_Payment_Gateway`,
you don't need to direct call the the `process_payment()` function.

you just need to create class that extends `WC_Payment_Gateway` and add that function on your class, it will automatically called from checkout process
see `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php` line  `777`

the `process_payment()` function should return an array with key `results` and `redirect_url`

example :

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Set order status
    $order->update_status( 'processing', __( 'Payment created from custom gateway' ) );

    // Reduce stock levels
    wc_reduce_stock_levels( $order_id );

    // Remove cart
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    // Return thankyou redirect
    return array(
        'result'    => 'success',
        'redirect'  => $this->get_return_url( $order ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes I created a class extending  'WC_Payment_Gateway' (look to the answer with code.it contains all the code of the plugin). The problem is how **to launch the creation of the order after the submit of the form on the chekout page**. And after the payment is done we will change the order status in the file  notification.php

Comment: @IhebSaad sorry, I'm not sure what you want.
do you mean you need to communicate with other site (payment provider) before processing order, and if you get success response from payment provider, then the order should be created / processed?

Comment: Yes exactly ! I want to create the order after the submit of the form in checkout page and change the order status(completed) after payment is done.

Comment: you shouldn't do submit your custom form on checkout page. You can validate it through method `validate_fields()` on your custom class with return `bool` (true or false), or check it on hook `woocommerce_checkout_process` 

you can see the code on for checkout process on `class-wc-checkout.php` file

`https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php`